# Can't remove keys from ssh-agent. Even rebooting doesn't help

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

A short time ago I noticed that there were three keys in my ssh-agent that I could not delete.  `ssh-add -l` showed three keys; I ran `ssh-add -D`, and was told "All identities removed."; but then an immediate `ssh-add -l` showed the same three keys.

If I log out and then back in, the keys are still there.  If I reboot the machine, the keys are still there.  If I delete the keyring directory in `/tmp`, I can't connect to `ssh-agent` any more, but upon logging out and back in, the keys are back.  They are invulnerable.

The keys are mine, not anyone else's, as far as I can tell.  I can access my usual local services with them.  But when I add one of the keys again with `ssh-add`, giving the path to a private key file, the new key has a different appearance in the output of `ssh-add -l`:

```
2048 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f /home/jruser/.ssh/jruser-keyname-20110418 (RSA)
```

vs. the original:

```
2048 00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e:0f jruser 04/18/2011 keyname (RSA)
```

Is there any way to sensibly account for this behavior?  I guess there are really two questions:

1. How do the keys managed to be retained even across reboots?  My basic knowledge of `ssh` suggests that keys always have to be added manually.
2. Why does `ssh-agent -D` lie to me about removing identities?

Comment: There's a Fedora/Red Hat bug too: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1205546

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it might be a bug.  I am having similar behavoir in Ubuntu 10.10.  A google search found a bug report for Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472477

To remove the extra keys I had showing, I just moved them out of the ~/.ssh directory.

Comment: Yes! This works for me. Thanks! I use Debian Wheezy beta 4.

Comment: Finally buckled down and investigated.  The culprit is gnome-keyring-daemon, which a) automatically loads all keys in ~/.ssh, and b) refuses to relinquish them.  The solution is to keep gnome-keyring-manager from ever starting up, which was strangely difficult by finally achieved by removing the program file's execute permission.

Comment: Is there a solution to this which _doesn't_ involve hobbling gnome-keyring-manager?   ie, fixing gnome-keyring-manager so it deletes keys it's told to?

Comment: It is 2018 and this is still relevant. Have to move the keys out of ~/.ssh

Comment: Wow. Remove the keys from ~/.ssh and put in other directory as @CarsonIp mentioned and then use a ssh-agent command in your bashrc to manually load the extra ssh keys from the other directory. PIMA!

Comment: Ran into this still in 2019, turns out you can disable just the ssh-agent functionality of gnome-keyring, see the section "Disable keyring daemon components" here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#SSH_keys

Comment: Deleting the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files didn't work for me. Turns out gpg-agent was caching them in a `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` file; I had to manually delete them from there.

Answer (score 3):

Your keys are stored as files in the hidden directory: /home/jruser/.ssh/ that's how they persist after reboots.  My guess the is that ssh-add -D is deleting them from memory but when you reboot they are read from the .ssh directory and so you have them again.

Comment: But `ssh-add -D` is NOT deleting them from memory.  It has no effect at all.